# how to create a receiving class java in Android manifest - Delphi

Tags: java, android, delphi, android-manifest

I have a simple application android in delphi. It is already the default sms app. But I can not get messages, I've read several posts here, and by what seems to need to create a class in java even using delphi.
Example: 
receiver android:name="" <-- In this field I should put the name of the java class, but how do I do this? My application is in Delphi.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create your own .java file, after with this java you need to create a jar, and after with this jar you need to include it in the application manager > android > librairies (in delphi berlin at least) and then in the android manifest you can add a reference to it

Comment: understand, i tried and in my classes.dex show the name of my class java,i put this classes.dex in my project and the file '.jar', right?